# Como: Preencher objeto Colecções de múltiplas fontes

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, linq

Gostaria de um auxílio em passar valores para minha propriedade
`private IEnumerable<OrderDetail> orderDetail;`.

Gostaria de preenchê-la, mas já procurei alguns exemplos e não achei algo com esta situação. Peço a ajuda dos colegas se puder mostrar alguma forma de realizar este procedimentos sem que precise ficar preenchendo dois *DataTable* para fazer *inner join* com o *Linq*.

Vou apresentar a estrutura das Classes abaixo e forma que estou realizando a busca no Banco de Dados.

```
 public class Order
    {
        public string orderNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }
        private DateTime requiredDate { get; set; }
        private DateTime shippedDate { get; set; }
        public int customerNumber { get; set; }
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
        private IEnumerable<OrderDetail> orderDetail;

        public virtual IEnumerable<OrderDetail> OrderDetails
        {
            get { return orderDetail; }
            set { orderDetail = value; }
        }

        public Order()
        {
            orderDetail = new List<OrderDetail>();
        }


//No formulário do Evento Load
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

     myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnString);
            myConnection.Open();

            MySqlDataAdapter conexaoAdapter = 
                new MySqlDataAdapter("select O.*, D.* " + 
                                        "from Orders O " +
                                        "INNER JOIN OrderDetails D " + 
                                        "ON O.orderNumber = D.orderNumber ", myConnection);
            conexaoAdapter.Fill(DataTableDatbase);

.....
}
```

Tentei usar com o *LINQ* mas não deu certo esta estrutura abaixo da erro:

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) D:\Samples Projetos\Pizzaria\TesteLinq\LINQ_TESTE2\Form1.cs 47  42  LINQ_TESTE2

```
   IEnumerable<Order> queryNamesScores =
    from Listorder in DataTableDatbase.Tables["Orders"].AsEnumerable()
    select new Order()
    {
        orderNumber = DataTableDatbase.Tables[0].Rows[0]["orderNumber"].ToString(),
         OrderDetails  = (from scoreAsText in DataTableDatbase.Tables["OrderDetails"].AsEnumerable()
                      select scoreAsText).ToList()
    };
```

Alguém tem algum exemplo, dica ou alguma estrutura para realizar este procedimento de preencher a propriedade tipo coleção da minha classe?

Comment: Não sei se o código tem mais algum problema mas o erro é devido a que *OrderDetails* está declarada como `IEnumerable<OrderDetail>` e você está a atribuir-lhe uma `List`. Retire `.ToList()` do `.... select scoreAsText).ToList()`

Comment: Mas tipo se olhar na classe Order eu tenho uma propriedade tipo List... Então como você montaria o exemplo acima?

Comment: @ramaral te garanto que o problema não está em atribuir List<OrderDetail> para IEnumerable<OrderDetail>, afinal a classe List<T> implementa IEnumerable<T> https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx isso é totalmente possível na orientação a objetos.

Comment: @Murilo Você tem razão, foi levado pelo texto do erro que diz que não pode converter os dois tipos

Comment: Entendo, é a primeira coisa que eu pensaria também, mas não tenho uma solução também.

Answer (score 1):

Veja um exemplo abaixo de como você pode esta fazendo isso.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string myConnString
        {
            get
            {
                return "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Teste;User ID=sa;Password=*****";
            }
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnString;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT orderNumber,orderDate,requiredDate,shippedDate,customerNumber,status,comments FROM Teste.dbo.Order_";

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable dtOrder_ = new DataTable();

                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dtOrder_);  

                var qrOrder = from row in dtOrder_.AsEnumerable()
                           select new Order
                           {
                               orderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row[0].ToString()),
                               orderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[1]),
                               requiredDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[2]),
                               shippedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[3]),
                               customerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row[4]),
                               status = Convert.ToBoolean(row[5]),
                               comments = Convert.ToString(row[6]),
                           };


                List<Order> OrderList = new List<Order>();
                // aqui você varre toda sua order e busca os detalhes
                foreach (var Ord in qrOrder)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd2.Connection = conn;
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT idDetails,   Details,    IdOrder,    orderNumber FROM Teste.dbo.OrderDetails WHERE orderNumber = @orderNumber";
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@orderNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ord.orderNumber;
                    SqlDataAdapter daOrderDetails = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    DataTable dtOrderDetails = new DataTable();

                    daOrderDetails.SelectCommand = cmd2;
                    daOrderDetails.Fill(dtOrderDetails);

                    var qrOrderDetail = from row in dtOrderDetails.AsEnumerable()
                                  select new OrderDetail
                                  {
                                      idDetails = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]),
                                      Details = Convert.ToString(row[1]),
                                      IdOrder = Convert.ToInt32(row[2]),
                                      orderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row[3]),
                                  };

                    Order order = new Order()
                    {
                        orderNumber = Ord.orderNumber,
                        orderDate = Ord.orderDate,
                        requiredDate = Ord.requiredDate,
                        shippedDate = Ord.shippedDate,
                        customerNumber = Ord.customerNumber,
                        status = Ord.status,
                        comments = Ord.comments,
                        // aqui você carregar o IEnumerable OrderDetail ou uma list 
                        OrderDetails = qrOrderDetail, /// ou  qrOrderDetail.ToList(),

                    };

                    OrderList.Add(order);
                }

                // fim 
                var sualista = OrderList;
            }
            catch (SqlException sqle)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: ");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public class OrderDetail
    {

        public int idDetails { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public int IdOrder { get; set; }
        public int orderNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public Int32 orderNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime requiredDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime shippedDate { get; set; }
        public int customerNumber { get; set; }
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public string comments { get; set; }
        private IEnumerable<OrderDetail> orderDetail;

        public virtual IEnumerable<OrderDetail> OrderDetails
        {
            get { return orderDetail; }
            set { orderDetail = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Tabelas do banco

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,[orderNumber]
      ,[orderDate]
      ,[requiredDate]
      ,[shippedDate]
      ,[customerNumber]
      ,[status]
      ,[comments]
  FROM [Teste].[dbo].[Order_]

SELECT TOP 1000 [idDetails]
      ,[Details]
      ,[IdOrder]
      ,[orderNumber]
  FROM [Teste].[dbo].[OrderDetails]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]